# Need to use manifest file mentioned in repo init

Tags: repo

I have a repo init command of the format `repo init -u url -m manifest.xml`.
This manifest file name will vary. After `repo init` and `repo sync`, I need to use that manifest name in my shell script. Any environment variable exists for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the name of your current manifest file in `.repo/manifest.xml`.

You will find such a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!  It is generated by repo and changes will be discarded.
If you want to use a different manifest, use `repo init -m <file>` instead.

If you want to customize your checkout by overriding manifest settings, use
the local_manifests/ directory instead.

For more information on repo manifests, check out:
https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/HEAD/docs/manifest-format.md
-->
<manifest>
  <include name="default.xml" />
</manifest>
```

This correspond to `repo init -u url -m default.xml`.

---

To get the value in your terminal you can use `xmllint` (`libxml2-utils` package):

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//include/@name)" .repo/manifest.xml
```