# How can I determine the URL that a repository was originally initialized from android repo tool with repo init -u <URL>?

Tags: git, repo

I have initialized repo using repo tool with command repo init -u .
How can I determine the url later ?
As that of any git repository we use below command,
git config --get remote.origin.url
Or
git remote show origin

Answer (score 4):

**To get the URL corresponding to `repo init -u <URL>`**

At the top of your workspace

```
$ cd .repo/manifests 
$ git remote -v
```

**To get the branch corresponding to `repo init -b <branch>`**

At the top of your workspace

```
$ cd .repo/manifests
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}
```

mostly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753364/2482441).

**To get the manifest name corresponding to `repo init -m <manifest.xml>`**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61011199/2482441).

Comment: Thank you Hugo, 
Is there any way to get branch(-b) and manifest xml file(-m) as well,

e.g. 
repo init -b icefish -m icefish_9.0.1.xml -u https://gerrit.automotivelinux.org/gerrit/AGL/AGL-repo